# How to find $g'(0)$ if $g(x)=\sin(f(x^2+x)-2x)$ and $f$ satisfies $|f(x)|\le x^2$ for all $x$?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

The problem goes as follows:

> Let $f(x)$ be a function such that $|{f(x)}|\le x^2$ $\forall x \in [-1,1/7]$.

The first part of the problem is prove that $\lim_{x\rightarrow0} \frac{f(x)}{x}=0$, which a simple $\delta-\epsilon$ argument (set $\delta=\epsilon$) is enough to do so.
However, I cannot do the second part of the problem:

> Let $g(x)=\sin(f(x^2+x)-2x)$ and find $g'(0)$.

My attempt:
It seems I should use the definition of the derivative of $g(x)$, hence I obtain
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\sin(f(x^2+x)-2x)-\sin(f(0))}{x}$$ but I don't know how to proceed from here.

Comment: Thank you for the modification! I see the pattern I should write the post in the next time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean to put $\lvert f(x)\rvert\le x^{2}$ since at $x=0$ we have equality so the inequality cannot be strict. In any case the first part of the problem shows you that the derivative of $f$ at $x=0$ is $0$. Simply apply chain rule to find $g'(0)$.

Comment: That was very careless of me...but thank you for the great solution!

Comment: No worries. You're welcome.